# How run an activity or a service of Android with Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I'm using "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" with Ionic 3, but it works only when your app is in background, not after kill. But, a notification "background tracking enabled" is appearing in notification bar.

I want to get a service running in background even when the app is killed. And by "killed" I mean: press home-button for a long time -> see all running apps -> swipe my app aside -> app killed OR press back-button for a long time -> app killed.

Comment: Why do you think this is possible?

Comment: @Jeroen Heier , Because of the notification "background tracking enabled", that appear in notification bar even after app killed. I think something working behind the scene, may be this is a "background location service". But i dont know how to handle it.